# If the chance of an event was $1/128$ and increased by $20\%$, what is the new chance?

Tags: probability, fractions, percentages

So I have something that has a 1/128 chance of occurring, let's say.  Suddenly, the chances of that thing happening are increased by 20%.  How is that fraction written?  Would you multiply 1/128 by 6/5 (yielding 3/320), or would you take 128, multiply it by 4/5, and then invert it (1/102)?

This isn't for homework, I'm merely curious.

Thank you

Comment: The answer is not very well defined. The increase can refer to increase in probability (as others interpreted it) or increase in odds - which is almost identical to the first interpretation since initial probability/odds are small, but would be very different if you had $127/128$ instead of $1/128$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $6/5=1.2$ is the correct approach.  This increases a value by $20\%$.  Multiplying by $4/5$ decreases a value by $20\%$, but inverting that is **not** the same as increasing by $20\%$.  It results in multiplying by $5/4$, which is an increase of $25\%$.  On top of that, $128 \cdot \frac 45=102.4,$ not $102$

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is correct.

Initial $p = \dfrac1{128}$, you need to increase $p$ by $20\%$

*Note*

Since $p = \dfrac1{128}$, i.e. in the form of a fraction, it is possible to obtain the correct result by manipulating its denominator only, but then you would need to **divide** the denominator by $1.2$,
i.e. multiply it by $\dfrac56$